# Removing content in specific directories from Google search results

Tags: google, google-search-console, robots.txt, search-results

We are using a plugin on our website to handle job application submissions. I found out recently that the applications were being uploaded into a public directory. We've had some individuals approach us asking us to remove there resumes from our system since they can be found doing a simple search on Google.

I've taken some steps to protect the information in these directories:

1. Used robot.txt to Disallow Google from accessing the directories.
2. Password protected the directories.

It's been two weeks since I've put these measures into place yet I'm still seeing files from these directories in Google search results.

What can I do to ensure that the files that are in these directories no longer appear in Google's index?

Thanks
-Brandon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is a good move. You might need to allow little bit more time for Google to remove it from the index.

You may also like to try: Remove URLs Tool
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en

Comment: Thank you! I've also tested one of the documents that was brought to my attention this morning using the "Remove Outdated Content" tool and received the following confirmation: This content is no longer live on the website.
We've confirmed the content no longer exists, or is blocked from Google.
Now you can submit your temporary removal request. The site's webmaster may receive a notice from Google that an outdated page removal was sent for this URL.

Comment: If you have a lot of the files, it can be a pain to submit them one by one, but that is pretty much the only removal option that Google offers.

Comment: Yeah, way too many files to remove one by one. But it looks like Google got the hint. I guess I just need to wait for the changes to propagate and the results removed from search results.